# Wordpress Twenty Seventeen Theme making Sub Menu split into 2 columns

Tags: css, wordpress, submenu

I am using the Twenty Seventeen Wordpress theme. I am trying to make the sub-menu items appear in 2 columns because I have several under one of my main menu items.

I tried to add to the "Additional CSS" area under customization the following... but nothing changed.

```
.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li {
    clear: initial;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
} 
.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li:nth-child(odd) {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 300px;
}
.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li:nth-child(even) {
    float: right;
}
```

I've also tried this... with no success...

```
.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}

.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li:nth-child(odd) {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li:nth-child(even) {
  float: right;
}
```

I also tried this... but then the submenu column got wider but it still didnt separate the items into 2 columns...

```
.sub-menu {
    width: 410px;
}
.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li:nth-child(odd) {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li:nth-child(even) {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: I just tried this that I found...   ul{
  columns: 2;
}    however, it made all of my menu go into 2 columns instead of just the sub-menu (no surprise) but what do I add to this to make it just the submenu... I tried to change it to this... .sub-menu  ul{
  columns: 2;
} but then it went back to regular one line menu and one line sub-menu?

Answer (score 0):

I found this and tried it and it worked!

```
.sub-menu {
  columns: 2;
}
```

I knew it had to be something simple, I just wasn't seeing...
Maybe this post will help someone else.